# SSRS - How to AVG then format a number

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to get the average handle time per call to display as HH:MM:SS.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to take the AVG(Field) and make it HH:MM:SS. I can either A) avg and get the a decimal number which represents seconds or format total seconds for all calls in HH:MM:SS. but can't seem to marry the two. I'm sure it's simple but can't find anything on here that works.

This was one of my attempts that didn't work. "=Format(Avg(Fields!AHT.Value), 'HH:MM:SS')"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does AHT contain? Is it a number of seconds?

Comment: AHT contains the total seconds for each call over the date range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like ...

```
=DATEADD(DateInterval.Second, AVG(Fields!AHT.Value), Today())
```

then format this textbox as Time in the textbox properties, under 'Number' or use the format code `T`

[image]

This gives this result..

[image]

All the expression does is take `Today()` which is only the date (therefore the time is 00:00:00) and then add the average number of seconds to it. So the actual result is today's date plus the time we want. Then format the textbox as `time` only, to hide the date portion.

Comment: This worked thank you!

Comment: Great! can you please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark to the left of the answer under the vote up/down buttons). This will help others find answers to similar questions in the future.

Comment: Done, I was wondering if there was a way to give you credit. First time posting things for the help on the problem and site guidance. :)

Comment: No problem. SO guidelines are followed fairly stringently sometimes. You might find a question get closed when you think it's perfectly valid. It's worth reading thru the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and help https://stackoverflow.com/help pages so you understand what is expected. You'll get better answers faster and earn reputation as you go, which gives you more privileges on the site.